# When does Angular update the view when there is a scope data change

Tags: angularjs

All:

When I change a $scope variable in a function, I wonder when can I trigger the data digest and update view?

Say I have a function like:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("main", function($scope) {
  $scope.data1 = "old data 1";
  $scope.data2 = "old data 2";

  function changedata() {
    this.data1 = "new data 1";
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < 2000; k++) {
          var data = i * j * k;
        }
      }
    }
    this.data2 = "new data 2";
  }
  $scope.changedata = changedata.bind($scope);
  
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-controller="main">
  <button ng-click="changedata()">Change data(click and wait a little bit time)</button>
  <div>{{data1}}</div>
  <div>{{data2}}</div>
  <div>I change data 1 first, then set a blocking delay and change data2 in the click handler, I wonder how can I make angular update the view immediately after data 1 changed rather than waiting for the function call finished? In another way, at what point does angular digest cycle get triggered?
</body>
</html>
```

When I click button, the data1 in the view never get updated until the function returns, I wonder if Angular digest data and update view based on function call?
If not, could anyone give a little detail **how angular check data dirty and run update?**

Thanks

Comment: could you reproduce the problem statement in plunkr?

Comment: How do you implement "a long time delay". If using $timeout, everything should be automatic (i.e. the first and the second scope changes should both appear in the view, one after the other)

Comment: JB Nizet is correct. If your long delay is, say, a very long JS function running continuously, then you will not see the update. If that's the case you can wrap that function in a `$timeout(..)` and it will sort it out.

Comment: another interesting detail about timeout not mentioned, if you call `$timeout` without passing in a delay parameter it will run the callback function immediately after the current $digest cycle, then call `$apply`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks, I do not use async pattern to do, it just a long time consuming blocking delay to emulate a data calculation process. After reading the comment, I guess my question is more about how to identify a digest cycle? For example say If I $watch a scope variable, **when** that $watch handler get called?

Comment: @Kuan You still don't have to handle it manually. Place your long calculation code inside `$timeout(function () { // your code })` and it will resolve itself.